# convert byte[] array to number of byte

Tags: java, arrays, byte

i have a byte[] array with even number's length. 
Now, i want byte[] array to break into half of its length with first two bytes in byte[] array as byte b1, next two as byte b2, and so on.

please help on this.
Thanks

Comment: Your question really isn't clear to me... in particular how you want to combine two bytes into one...

Answer (score 0):

Is this homework? I guess your main problem is combining pairs of bytes into double-bytes. This is achieved with what's called a left shift (`<<`), the byte is 8 bits, so shift by eight:

```
int doubleByte = b1 + (b2 << 8);
```

Note, I use `b1` as a lower byte, and `b2` as a higher byte.

The rest is easy: allocate an array of `int` that's half the length of your byte array, and then iterate through your byte array to build up your new `int` array. Hope this helps.

Comment: well, thanks for you effort friends. Eg: byte{130C00D2C00001} is what i have. To perform some operations on 13,0C,00 so on, i need them separated. i guess you now you where clear.

Comment: Sorry, this comment isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I understand your question totally wrong.

```
public class Main {
    // run this
    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        // create the array and split it
        Main.splitArray(new byte[10]);
    }

    // split the array
    public static void splitArray(byte[] byteArray) {
        int halfSize = 0; // holds the half of the length of the array
        int length = byteArray.length; // get the length of the array
        byte[] b1 = new byte[length / 2]; // first half
        byte[] b2 = new byte[length / 2]; // second half
        int index = 0;

        if (length % 2 == 0) { // check if the array length is even
            halfSize = length / 2; // get the half length

            while (index < halfSize) { // copy first half
                System.out.println("Copy index " + index + " into b1's index " + index);
                b1[index] = byteArray[index];
                index++;
            }

            int i = 0; // note the difference between "i" and "index" !
            while (index < length) { // copy second half
                System.out.println("Copy index " + index + " into b2's index " + i);// note the difference between "i" and "index" !
                b2[i] = byteArray[index];// note the difference between "i" and "index" !
                index++;
                i++; //dont forget to iterate this, too
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("Length of array is not even.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort my friends. i got the answer